# Python can't import urllib2 (gives an error)

Tags: python, syntax, urllib2, urllib, traceback

I just started with programming, I wanted to import the urllib resource but when I just use this code:

```
import urllib2
```

It worked 2 months ago (took a break).
It gives me this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib2
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1157, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 58, in <module>
    import textwrap
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py", line 10, in <module>
    import string, re
  File "/home/younes/Python/string.py", line 11
    for total:
             ^
```

I used Python 2 for that, also when using Python 3 it doesn't find the module. (it also doesn't find the urllib3 module?)
I have reinstalled Python but it didn't work.
I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `/home/younes/Python/string.py` is preventing import of the standard library module [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) which in turn prevent import of modules depending on the `string` module. In addition to that, the file has an syntax error.

Remove the file or rename the file. If there's `/home/younes/Python/string.pyc`, also remove/rename it.

Comment: That worked! Great thank you! do you have any idea why it did that?

Comment: @user3104326, **it did that**? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You have a file called string.py which shadows the builtin string module. Also, consider starting with a newer Python 3 instead of the old Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

if use python3 , from urllib import requests or import urllib.request and usage:

urllib.request.urlopen("http:xxx")